# Chartist url on click with a bar chart - javascript

Tags: javascript, chartist.js

I am trying to get the onClick feature to work with Chartist, using the following code to open a new Url (without JQuery):

```
var chart = new Chartist.Bar('#chart1', {
    labels: [1, 2, 3, 4],
    series: [[5, 2, 8, 3]]
  }, {
  distributeSeries: false
},{
  seriesBarDistance: 20,
  low: 0,
  high: 10
});
chart.on('draw', function(data) {
    if(data.type === 'bar') {
        data.element._node.onclick = func (){window.location = "www.google.com"}


    }
});
```

But when I implement this, it doesn't wait for on click, it automatically opens www.google.com.

How can I get it to wait for the click?

Is someone able to clarify what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know about your problem but `func ()` is not a valid javascript keyword

You should change it to :

```
data.element._node.onclick = function(){ 
  window.location = "www.google.com"; 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

### Try this

**HTML**

```
   <div id="chartContainer" style="height: 360px; width: 100%;"></div>
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer",
{

  data: [
  {
         type: "bar",
         cursor:"pointer",
         click: onClick,          
         dataPoints: [
                 { label: "Google", y: 85, link:"http://google.com/" },
                 { label: "Bing", y: 15, link:"http://bing.com/"},
                 { label: "Yahoo Search", y: 13, link:"http://search.yahoo.com/" },
                 { label: "DuckDuckGo", y: 6, link:"http://www.duckduckgo.com/" },
                 { label: "DogPile", y: 3, link: "http://www.dogpile.com/" }        
           ]
          }
       ]
     });

  chart.render();


function onClick(e){ 
        window.open(e.dataPoint.link,'_blank');  
        };
```

https://jsfiddle.net/canvasjs/ccxob6bp/